# can two same pieces of code give different results?

Tags: python, kivy

my first day of learning kivy framework .

the kivy website shows :

```
import kivy
kivy.require('2.1.0') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

to create an application and it works as expected . followed manually and made a file named first.py and wrote :

```
import kivy
kivy.require('2.1.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):
    
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="hello world")
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp.run()
```

and this code is showing the error :

```
 d:/kivlearn/first.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\sahil\.kivy\logs\kivy_23-10-12_25.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.3
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.6.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.2.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "D:\kivlearn\kivy_venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.11.6 (tags/v3.11.6:8b6ee5b, Oct  2 2023, 14:57:12) [MSC v.1935 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "D:\kivlearn\kivy_venv\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 190 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "d:\kivlearn\first.py", line 14, in <module>
     MyApp.run()
 TypeError: App.run() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
(kivy_venv) PS D:\kivlearn>
```

is there a difference in both the pieces of code? what to do?

i tried switching back to global installation rather than the environment , but the problem persisted.

Comment: There are 2 differences between the 2 pieces of code posted; one is exactly the line cited in the error message, the other is trivial.

Comment: In the first you have `MyApp().run()` and in the second you have `MyApp.run()`.

Comment: You can use a text comparison tool to easily catch differences like this.  Most IDEs include comparison (diff)  tools.  If your IDE does not include that ability, then consider using 3rd party tools such as [Beyond Compare](https://www.scootersoftware.com/download/v3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two pieces of code are not the same, note in particular:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

vs.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp.run()
```

The first example instantiates `MyApp`, and then calls `run`, the second only calls the method on the class object. This also explains why you see the error message that you see (self doesn't exist in the second context).

Answer (score 1):

The code is not the same. You forgot to add the parentheses after `MyApp` in your version. `MyApp` is a class that needs to be instantiated first.

Instead of

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp.run()
```

write

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Literally seconds in it!

Comment: @PhilipAdler this question should be closed as a typo anyway. Don't answer typo questions

Comment: @Pho I didn't realise - is there a guideline to that effect?

Comment: @PhilipAdler a guideline for what is a typo, or a guideline saying typo questions should be closed? I don't know about the former, but forgetting to create an instance when the example is right in front of you certainly fits the description in my book. For the latter -- that's why the close reason exists.

Comment: @PhilipAdler I didn't know either but agree with you. A typo is generally not a problem that is likely to be reproduced by others, so it is not helpful to answer such questions. However I would suggest to highlight the typo in a comment and vote for closing the question.